# How can I check if the currently shown ImageTarget is equal to the randomly selected ImageTarget?

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, vuforia, unity-game-engine

I am posting the Quiz.cs script where I pick a random game object. Now in the DefaultTrackableEventHandler I need to check if the randomly chosen game object's ImageTarget is equal to the ImageTarget shown to the camera !

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Vuforia;

public class Quiz : MonoBehaviour 
{

     public GameObject[] models;
     public GameObject currentPoint;
     int index;
     public AudioSource correctAudio;
     public AudioSource notcorrectAudio;
    //QuizLogic test ;
    //public ImageTargetBehaviour checck;
    //private TrackableBehaviour mTrackable;

    //public GameObject[] sounds;
    void Start()
    { 

        StateManager sm = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager();
        IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> activeTrackables = sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours();

        models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("numbers");
        index = Random.Range (0, models.Length);
        currentPoint = models[index];
        print ("Trackable " +currentPoint.name);
        currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
        foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in activeTrackables) 
        {
            // As you iterate, you compare with current game object name
            // if you have 3 and 5 and target object is 5 then you get a match.
            if( tb.GetComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>().ImageTarget.Name==currentPoint.GetComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>().ImageTarget.Name )
            { 
                print ("Congratulations you have chosen the correct ImageTarget");
            }
            else
            { 
                print ("Try another one !");
            }
        }
}
}
```

Now when I call this script into OnTrackingFound() in the DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs (when I show to the camera an ImageTarget to compare it with the randomly selected ImageTarget) I get this error: 
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is the DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Vuforia
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
    /// </summary>
    public class QuizLogic : MonoBehaviour,
    ITrackableEventHandler
    {
        #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

        private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;


        #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES


        Quiz quiz;



        #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

        void Start()
        {

            mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
            if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            {
                mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS



        #region PUBLIC_METHODS
        public GameObject show;
        public GameObject hide;

        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
        /// tracking state changes.
        /// </summary>
        public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
            TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
            TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED )
            {
                OnTrackingFound();


            }

            else
            {
                OnTrackingLost();

            }
        }

        #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS



        #region PRIVATE_METHODS


        private void OnTrackingFound()
        {

            show.SetActive(true);
            Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            AudioSource[] audiocomponents  = GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>(true);

            // Enable rendering:
            foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }


            // Enable colliders:
            foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }

            //Enable AudioSource 
            foreach (AudioSource component in audiocomponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
            quiz.GetComponent<Quiz> ();

        }


        private void OnTrackingLost()
        {
            hide.SetActive(true);
            Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            AudioSource[] audiocomponents  = GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>(true);
            // Disable rendering:
            foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }

            // Disable colliders:
            foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }


            //Disable AudioSource
            //foreach (AudioSource component in audiocomponents)
            //{
            //  component.enabled = false;
            //}



            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
        }



        #endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
    }
}
```

Please Help me with this because I am new to Vuforia !!! I would be grateful if you help

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the NullReferenceException. What you want to achieve is pretty much irrelevant in that context.

Just check in which line of code the NullReferenceException occurs, find the reference (in that line) which is unassigned, make sure it is assigned properly and that problem will be solved.

Comment: This is the line that gives the error: 
 quiz.GetComponent<Quiz> ();

in this line I am calling the Quiz script in the Default trackableEventHandler , OnTrackingFound () function

Comment: There are two issues with this line. First: `quiz` is never assigned a value, thus it is null, meaning you'll get a NullReferenceException when you try calling one of it's members (which is what's happening to you). Second: the line `quiz.GetComponent<Quiz>();` has no effect. `GetComponent` only returns you the component (if it exists), it does not do anything with it.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to check in the OnTrackingFound() function if the randomly selected object taken from Quiz.cs is same as the object being shown to the camera. Can you help me to do this ? I would be grateful